# Real linear tranformation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, transformation

When do we say that a transformation $T$ which takes the complex number field onto itself is real-linear?

I need to know it for my homework but I can't seem to find the definition anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plane of complex numbers is a two dimensional vector space over the real numbers, its standard basis is $1,\,i$.

A map $T:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is *real linear*, if additive ($T(x+y)=Tx+Ty$) and preserves multiplication by *real* scalars:
$$T(\lambda x)=\lambda\,T(x)$$
For all *real* number $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

We could also say $\Bbb C$-linear, that would require this last property for all *complex* $\lambda$'s as well.